# Parametric Curve and Arc Length

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, parametric-functions, homework

Graph the curve $x=\sin(t) + \sin(1.5 t), y=\cos(t)$ and find its length correct to four decimal places

I tried Parametric Plot but it keeps telling me there's arguments against it.

`ParametricPlot[{Sin[t] + Sin[1.5 t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}]` is what I was trying.

Comment: what about the arc length part?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a comma separating the equations from the varied term:

```
ParametricPlot[{x = Sin[t] + Sin[1.5 t], y = Cos[t]} , {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Use [`ArcLength`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcLength.html)

```
ArcLength[{x = Sin[t] + Sin[1.5 t], y = Cos[t]} , {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

> 8.35512