# Measuring the length of any function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Measuring the length of any function?
for example, if y = f(x),
what is the length of the function curve between x = 2 to x = 5?

Comment: See also [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integration). Beware that calculating arc length leads to integrals that are sometimes not evaluated explicitly, even for a simple polynomial such as `f[x_] := x^3+x^4`. Use numerical evaluation `N` in that case. Related posts on this side include [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193346).

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(59756)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59756), [(115401)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115401), [(133133)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133133). Related: [(137678)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137678)

Answer (score 7):

```
ArcLength[{x, f[x]}, {x, 2, 5}]
```

Or calculate the numerical result.

```
ArcLength[{x, f[x]}, {x, 2., 5}]
ArcLength[{x, f[x]}, {x, N@2, 5}]
```

Comment: Or `ArcLength[{x, f[x]}, {x, 2, 5}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]`